# Auto Casting Oracle column to Sql Server 2005 native type

Tags: oracle, t-sql

I have a Oracle linked server (10.g) on a Sql server 2005.
Trying to import oracle table schema(s) into SQL using

```
Select * into ttdsls030010 
from openQuery(hades,'select * from baan.ttdsls030010 where rownum =1');
```

This throws an `Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP to datetime`

Is there a way to autocast Oracle type to Sql type ?

p.s:
Essentially, although it is possible to cast type in Oracle using to_char() etc.  The notion here is that Oracle table schema could change any time i.e adding or deleting columns. If such has happened, I need to refresh local (sql) schemas to correspond to that of Oracle.

Comment: I saw [this post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2009/07/31/linked-server-vs-openquery-for-handling-data-type-conversions.aspx) which implies that the conversion should occur automatically, and points to a possible problem with the date data...

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the failure is down to a date value that isn't supported by the MS SQL Server datetime - as the [documentation for the datetime datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) shows, it only handles dates since 1753, whereas the Oracle dbtimestamp goes from about 4700 BC...